# Samba with individual users per shared directory

Tags: linux, samba

I've mapped two directories as Samba shared folders.

I wish to give a user access to site1, but not www.

How is this accomplished?

```
[global]
workgroup=WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server Version %v

# interfaces = lo wlan0 192.168.0.1/24
hosts allow = 127. 192.168.0.

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 50

security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
# security = auto
# server role = standalone


[www]
        comment = Apache WWW Directory
        path = /var/www
        read only = no
        force create mode = 0775
        create mask = 0775
        force directory mode = 0775
        create directory = 0775

[site1]
        comment = Bidjunction Lib Directory
        path = /var/www/site1
        read only = no
        force create mode = 0775
        create mask = 0775
        force directory mode = 0775
        create directory = 0775
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[site1]
comment = Bidjunction Lib Directory
path = /var/www/site1
read only = no
force create mode = 0600
create mask = 0600
force directory mode = 0700
create directory = 0700
valid users = <username>
```

Make sure that your file system persmissions make it possible for the user to enter the directory. In case you want to make the share available to several users, just don't add more users to valid users. Change your masks to allow groups, i. e.0660 instead of 0600 and change username to @groupname. Finally set force group to groupname. This way you can have different owners but all users in @groupname can modify the files.

Answer (score 0):

You should define users with `valid users` keyword.

Check the security page for samba at http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html